# Line Breaks In Announcement Command Not Working

Tags: java, discord, discord-jda

I am currently learning Java and have decided to work on a discord bot just for fun, but I have ran into a problem. I was working on an announce command that would send an announcement to a certain channel but the problem is that the line breaks do not show up in the output when put in the input (Note: I am using normal line breaks "shift+enter", I am not using "\n"). For example, here is an input I have put in:

```
-announce Hello there! Hope you're having a wonderful day!

Hello there again! I hope YOU'RE having a wonderful day!

Test

Test
```

But it sends the embed to the channel looking like this:
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xc2mt.png)

This is my code:

```
@Override
    public void onGuildMessageReceived(GuildMessageReceivedEvent event) {
        String[] args = event.getMessage().getContentRaw().split("\\s+");
        String msg = event.getMessage().getContentRaw();
        if (args[0].equalsIgnoreCase("-announce")) {
            if (args.length < 2) {

                EmbedBuilder embed = new EmbedBuilder();
                embed
                        .setDescription("Usage: -announce <test>")
                        .setColor(Color.CYAN);
                event.getChannel().sendMessage(embed.build()).queue();
                embed.clear();
            } else {
                try {
                    TextChannel textChannel = event.getJDA().getTextChannelById("CHANNEL-ID");
                    if (textChannel.canTalk()) {
                        EmbedBuilder embed = new EmbedBuilder();
                        String message = "";
                        for (int i = 1; i < args.length; i++) {
                            message += args[i] + " ";
                        }
                        embed

                                .setColor(Color.CYAN)
                                .setDescription(message);
                        textChannel.sendMessage(embed.build()).queue();
                        embed.clear();
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're removing all newlines with your `split("\\s+")`. You should use a `substring` instead:

```java
String message = msg.substring(msg.indexOf(' ') + 1);
embed.setDescription(message);
```